# Oracle item to org API returns status 'E'

Tags: oracle, api, plsql, oracle-apps

I am using `EGO_ITEM_PUB.ASSIGN_ITEM_TO_ORG` API to assign one item of another organization to my choice of organization.

At the end of the procedure I am using the following code to fetch the result of API operations:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('==='); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Return Status: '||x_return_status); 

IF (x_return_status <> FND_API.G_RET_STS_SUCCESS) THEN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error Message Count :'||x_msg_count); 
END IF; 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('==='); 

EXCEPTION 
WHEN OTHERS THEN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exception Occured :'); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLCODE ||':'||SQLERRM); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('===');
```

At the end of the procedure, following is the output I get (The code executes smoothly):

```
===
Return Status: E
Error Message Count :1
===
```

I checked it into the database the item against the organization of my choice, but it does not exist.Neither is there any exception caused.I am confused as I am a beginner. I tried searching the meaning behind E but could not find anything. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

By adding following lines, we can retrieve the error message:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Status: '||x_return_status);
IF (x_return_status <> FND_API.G_RET_STS_SUCCESS) THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error Messages :');
Error_Handler.GET_MESSAGE_LIST(x_message_list=>x_message_list);
FOR j IN 1..x_message_list.COUNT LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x_message_list(j).message_text);
END LOOP;
END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
dbms_output.put_line('Exception Occured :');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLCODE ||':'||SQLERRM);
```